# Writing System Tests in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit5

### Preface

I'm deliberatly talking about system tests. We do have a rather exhaustive suite of unit tests, some of which use mocking, and those aren't going anywhere. The system tests are supposed to complement the unit tests and as such mocking is not an option.

### The Problem

I have a rather complex system that only communicates via REST and websocket events.
My team has a rather large collection of (historically grown) system tests based JUnit.
I'm currently migrating this codebase to JUnit5.

The tests usually consist of an `@BeforeAll` in which the system is started in a configuration specific to the test-class, which takes around a minute. Then there is a number of independent tests on this system.

The problem we routinely run into is that booting the system takes a considerable amount of time and may even fail. One could say that the booting itself can be considered a test-case. JUnit handles lifecycle methods kind of weirdly - the time they take isn't shown in the report; if they fail it messes with the count of tests; it's not descriptive; etc.

I'm currently looking for a workaround, but what my team has done over the last few years is kind of orthogonal to the core idea of JUnit (cause it's a unit testing framework).

Those problems would go away if I replaced the `@BeforeAll`with a test-method (let's call it `@Test public void boot(){...}`) and introduce an order-dependency (which is pretty easy using JUnit 5) that enforces `boot` to run before any other test is run.

So far so good! This looks and works great. The actual problem starts when the tests aren't executed by the CI server but by developers who try to troubleshoot. When I try to start a single test `boot` is filtered from the test execution and the test fails.

Is there any solution to this in JUnit5? Or is there a completely different approach I should take?

I suspect there may be a solution in using `@TestTemplate` but I'm really not sure how to procede. Also afaik that would only allow me to generate new named tests that would be filtered as well. Do I have to write a custom test-engine? That doesn't seem compelling.

Comment: Is it an option to use dependency injection and provide mocks/stubs so you don't need to fire up a whole working environment?

Comment: I'm deliberatly talking about system tests. We do have a rather exhaustive suite of unit tests, some of which use mocking, and those aren't going anywhere. The system tests are supposed to complement the unit tests and as such mocking is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This more general testing problem then related to Junit5. In order to skip very long boot up you can mock some components if it is possible. Having the booting system as a test does not make sense because there are other tests depending on that. Better to use @beforeAll in this case as it was before. For testing boot up, you can make separate test class for that which will run completely independent from other tests. 
Another option is to group this kind of test and separate from the plain unit test and run it only if needed (for example before deployment on CI server). This really depends on specific use case and should those test be part of regular build on your local machine.

The third option is to try to reduce boot time if it possible. This is option if you can't use mocks/stubs or exclude those tests from regular build.

Comment: My question is very specific to JUnit5 and is about system tests. So your generous advice to _do unit tests instead_ doesn't help at all.

Comment: Sorry but i did not tell you to use unit tests instead of system tests.